# google maps javascript v3 api not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I've tried all possible solutions but the map just isn't showing. My webview just shows blank.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
var map;  " +
function initialize() {    
var latitude = 0;    
var longitude = 0;    
if (window.android){      
    latitude = window.android.getLatitude();      
    longitude = window.android.getLongitude();    
    }    

var myOptions = {      
        zoom: 20,      
        center: myLatLng      
        }    
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),      myOptions);
}  

function centerAt(latitude, longitude){    
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);    
    map.panTo(myLatLng);
    }
</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 100px; width=100px;">This is the map canvas</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">initialize();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've narrowed down to this line: map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),      myOptions);

When this line is executed, it fails.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Regards,
Dexter

Answer (score 0):

I can't see `myLatLng` definition other than in `centerAt()` function. You need to pass Google Maps `LatLng` object to the `center` attribute of `myOptions`:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

var myOptions = {      
    zoom: 20,      
    center: myLatLng      
}  
...
```

And there is also a strange thing which I can't understand:

```
var map;  " +
          ^ ^
```

Answer (score 0):

my bad, submitted the wrong code. Anyway, the major issue here is the  connection. That took me a long time to realize it since i was just focusing on the codes.

Thanks.